# Will my F1 visa cancellation affect my application for a B1 visa?

Tags: indian-citizens, b1-b2-visas, f1-visas, visa-cancellation

In the past, my F1 visa was canceled upon arrival by the US Department of Homeland Security. They had stated"Insufficient Funds" in the cancellation description, failing to give the bank statements on arrival. Now I have to apply for a B1 visa as part of company travel. Does my F1 visa cancellation affect this B1 application?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Without additional information, it may be difficult for anyone to offer anything but an opinion, which is not the format here. Can you edit your question and explain the circumstances? It could make if difference whether you completed your studies or whether there were failures that led to the school cancelling your SEVIS record which, in turn, meant that the F1 was no longer valid.

Comment: @Giorgio I had to return to India as the Homeland Security canceled my F1 visa upon arrival in the US, stating insufficient funds. Now after three years, I have an opportunity to work for my company in the US. I'm going to attend an interview for B1 Visa. Now a question remains in my head that they had canceled my F1 visa earlier, does it affect my work permit visa now?

Comment: Are you sure that a B1 visa will allow you to work in the US? There are only *very* limited circumstances where this is at all possible since B1 is normally supposed to be for 'conducting business' which is not the same thing as 'working'..

Comment: A B1 visa for a job interview is not a work visa. If you were not permitted entry, despite holding an F1 visa, it suggests there may have been questions on your purpose. Now, first you said B1 visa for your company travel, then job interview to work. Those who review your B1 application will be able to review your entire US immigration record. My vote to close is for that reason: what you are intending and asking is unclear.

Comment: The question is not opinion based. `Will my F1 visa cancellation affect my application for a B1 visa?` **Yes it will affect it** because the cancellation and your return to India are part of your immigration history which will be reviewed when you are being evaluated in this new application. That said we cannot tell the outcome, they can overlook it because your current application and profile is strong. The fact that it affects it does not mean the outcome is determined.

Comment: @phoog yes, see OP edits to the question after I asked for additional info.

Comment: @Giorgio I don't see any mention of a job interview, only, in a comment, of a visa interview.

Comment: @phoog sorry, you're correct... it was OP's comment "I have an opportunity to work for my company in the US. I'm going to attend an interview for B1 Visa."

Comment: Thank you, everyone. Hope tomorrows interviews gives us an answer to this question.

Comment: @PavanSky if it does, please post an answer to this question (and, presumably, accept it) for the benefit of others.

Comment: They have rejected this Visa, stating the previous cancellation!!